# Google Apps Email Settings API - Signature Settings

Tags: google-api

I am somewhat new to code, and even more so to the Google Apps API. In the organization I work with, I have so far managed to write a couple of console apps that we run to apply signatures, and manage mailbox delegates as needed.

In regards to the Email Settings API, specifically the signatures portion, is there a way to check this box:

"Insert this signature before quoted text in replies and remove the "--" line that precedes it."

via the Email Settings API? I've looked through the API documentation, and even the .NET api reference docs, with no avail. Any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was available while it was a lab (through the admin console, not API), but not anymore now that it has 'graduated'.

It has now been submitted as an official feature request. Hopefully more people request it.

I was told that setting the footer through the API does show up before quoted text, so if that is true, and all you need is a footer for everyone in organization, you might be in luck.